# OnPageSetPublishedToPost & Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is the

> OnPageSetPublishedToPost

event supported in Tridion 2011. I am having real difficulty getting this event to fire.

I am deploying legacy events system code to Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I gave up (it appears it is not supported) and rewrote using the new events architecture.

Answer (score 5):

Legacy Events handlers, are not fully compatible with Tridion 2011.

> TOM event handlers will no longer be triggered for publishing,
> resolving and (for Audience Manager contacts import) Keyword save.

The [Legacy Event Adapter](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/LegacyEventAdapter.aspx) can help firing some of these events, but unfortunately I think **OnPageSetPublishedToPost** is not one of them. You can find a lot of useful info on the companion article though

May not be the answer you are looking for, but for this specific event handler you can consider a rewrite to the new event system model. You can mix both old style and new event handlers on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

Try events like the following. This should work. What did you try so far?

```
 EventSystem.Subscribe<PublishTransaction, SaveEventArgs>(YourMethod, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

and

```
  EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishEventArgs>(YourMethod, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

Comment: I have to re-use a legacy event code base from a 2009 implementation.

Comment: The Tridion 2011 Event system is fundamentally different from the 2009 event system. In 2011 the events are much more fine grained. You'll have to analyze which new event best matches the 2009 OnPageSetPublishedToPost event. The PublishTansaction-Save-Committed and Page-Publish-Committed events should be able to help you.

Comment: Tridion 2011 allows legacy (2009) events to be used. I am using several different ones, such as OnComponentSavePost. The only one that is refusing to fire is OnPageSetPublishedToPost. I have enabled it in the snap-in, and the event config targets the correct publication. I know that some events triggers are not available in 2011, I wonder is this one of them.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question about legacy event systems with Tridion 2011

Comment: Do you have a separate Publisher machine?  If so, you'll need to deploy your DLL and enable the config there.  Also, maybe the release notes contains info on unavailable events?